# Remove integer from each line with sed

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed, command-line

I have a list of strings that I want to remove the number and colon from the beginning of every string. How can I do this with `sed`?

When using:

```
printf '%s\n' '1:I am a sample line 1: line' '2:schafe' '11:11:11:12:' 'a'"'" | sed 's/^[0-9]\://g'
```

I would like to end up with:

```
I am a sample line 1: line
schafe
11:11:12:
a'
```

however running the command above seems to leave the `11:11:11:12:` line untouched. I'd like `sed` to match any size number if possible.

I am using BSD sed (from macOS) but I also have access to GNU sed if that is necessary.

Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/^[0-9]*://'`

Comment: @Beta That works, thanks! How come that doesn't match strings like `3a:string`? I thought an asterisk was to match any number of any character

Comment: @leetbacoon Asterisk matches anything in _globs_.  Sed, however, does _not_ use _globs_; it uses _regular expressions_.  In a regular expression, `*` mean zero-or-more-of-the-preceding-character.

Comment: @John1024 Ohhhh okay that makes sense, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This may not do what you intend. It will remove any leading `:` if the that line begins with a `:` or `:`'s. You should change it to `sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*://' file`which matches your original question.

Comment: @potong Won't that only match lines that begin with two or more numbers with a following colon, e.g. `26:` or `924:` but not `6:`

Comment: @leetbacoon `[0-9]` will match 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9. `[0-9]*` will match the same zero or more times. Put together and add a `:` then `[0-9][0-9]*:` will match one or more 0-9 followed by a `:`. See @John1023 comment. Another way (if your sed version allows) is to use `[0-9]\+:` where `\+` means one or more of the preceeding regexp.

Comment: Good catch @potong! I'll add it to the current answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta) and [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong):

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*://'
```

This will match either one or more numbers before a `:`.

`sed 's/^[0-9]*://'` was originally used, however this could also match strings containing a `:` at the beginning (no number).

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer when I can (have to wait 2 days). @Beta, if you want to post that as an answer I can accept that instead if you want.

Comment: Thank you, but no. I didn't put in the effort to write a real Answer (and as potong pointed out, I missed a failure case), so I can't accept an Acceptance.